# Why pymongo doesn't work with python3 and it only works with python2

Tags: python, mongodb, ubuntu-10.04, pymongo

```
user@ubuntu:~/Documents/MongoDB$ python2
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:09:56) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from pymongo import Connection
>>> 
user@ubuntu:~/Documents/MongoDB$ python3
Python 3.1.2 (r312:79147, Sep 27 2010, 09:45:41) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from pymongo import Connection
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pymongo
```

Question> I don't know why pymongo doesn't work with my python 3. Any idea?

> // Updated solution for this OP based on the helps below //
>
> First, still don't understand why this post got down-vote!
>
> Step1> http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymongo3#downloads
>
> Step2> Download pymongo3-1.9b1.tar.gz
>
> Step3> unzip it by using tar xzf pymongo3-1.9b1.tar.gz
>
> Step4> cd pymongo3-1.9b1
>
> Step5> sudo python3 setup.py install
>
> If you followed all above instructions, the pymongo should be ready
>   for your P3:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because you didn't install it for Python 3. You have to install a module for each version of Python that you have in order to access it from that version.This is all assuming that the module is compatible with each version of Python that you have.

Comment: You also need a different package for Python 3: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymongo3

Comment: The link is dead. Anyway, as @Rafe Kettler said you need python3 mongodb. In Ubuntu use: `pip3 install [package-name]` for installing p3 packages. Using only `pip install` will install p2 package by default.